# Subquery in PHP to extract data to Excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, subquery, extract

I have two tables:

```
biometrics - records in and out of employees
emp - employee records
```

In my biometrics table, there is a status.

```
0 - if the employee went out
1 - if the employee went in
```

The employee can have multiple 0 and 1 status in a day because you timed in and timed out also when having a break. so the status can be like this:

```
time_created status
9:00          1       ---  time in
12:00         0       ---  time out for break
13:00         1       ---  time in again after break
18:00         0       ---  time out
```

so the employee can have multiple breaks.

I already have the correct query for this but here is the problem. I'm making a program that records all breaks. The problem when I extract it to Excel, the "timeout" column and "timediff" (column that shows total number of hours and minutes the employee spent on his/her break) column is not showing. This two columns are products of sub-queries.

Here is my code:

```
        if(isset($_POST['timediff'])){
        header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Export_Date.csv');

            $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
            if(!$con){
                echo "Error connection";
                    }

            $select_db = mysql_select_db('sample', $con);
            if(!$select_db){
                echo "Error to select database";
                    }
            mysql_set_charset("utf8", $con);

    $myquery2 = mysql_query("select g.empno, emp.emp_fname, emp.emp_fname,    emp.position, emp.office , g.date_created, min(g.time_created), g.timeout, timediff(g.timeout, min(g.time_created))
FROM
(
select id_biometrics, empno,date_created, time_created, (
 SELECT min(s.time_created) FROM biometrics s

   WHERE s.status like '0' AND s.time_created > base.time_created
 AND s.empno= base.empno AND s.date_created = base.date_created 

   ORDER BY s.time_created ASC) as timeout 
from biometrics base
where base.status like '1'

) g, emp
WHERE emp.empno = g.empno AND NOT (g.timeout = (SELECT min(time_created) FROM biometrics    where status like '1'))

GROUP BY g.empno, g.timeout

ORDER BY g.date_created;");

        //While loop to fetch the records
        $contents =     "empno,emp_fname,emp_lname,position,office,date_created,timeout,timein,timediff\n";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myquery2))
        {
            $contents.=$row['empno'].",";
            $contents.=$row['emp_fname'].",";
            $contents.=$row['emp_lname'].",";
            $contents.=$row['position'].",";
            $contents.=$row['office'].",";
            $contents.=$row['date_created'].",";
            $contents.=$row['min(g.time_created)'].",";
            $contents.=$row['g.timeout'].",";
            $contents.=$row['timediff(g.timeout, min(g.time_created)']."\n";

        }

        $contents_final = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($contents, "UTF-16LE","UTF-8");
        print $contents_final;
        }
        ?>
```

The "timein" is showing. only the last two columns: "timeout" (g.timeout) and "timediff" is not showing. I don't know what is wrong because in MySQL Workbench, this query is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! haha. I use this method to print it,

```
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myquery2))
        {
            $contents.=$row[0].",";
            $contents.=$row[1].",";
            $contents.=$row[2].",";
            $contents.=$row[3].",";
            $contents.=$row[4].",";
            $contents.=$row[5].",";
            $contents.=$row[6].",";
            $contents.=$row[7].",";
            $contents.=$row[8]."\n";

        }
```

Thanks halfer for the print_r($row).. It showed me that every column is inside an array thus I printed it by providing indexes. :D :D

Comment: Righto. I think if you pass `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to the fetch method (see the docs to double-check the name) you can access the columns by name rather than by numeric index. Still at least is is now working! Don't forget to self-accept your own answer.

Comment: ok, I will start on studying PDO and mysqli now. hahahaha. thanks again. :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias your columns in your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT ... timediff(g.timeout, min(g.time_created)) AS mytimediff
FROM ...
```

The column can then be accessed as `mytimediff`.

There may be another way to read this without the alias: temporarily, try adding `print_r($row)` inside your loop, to see how this column is referenced without an explicit SQL alias. That said, I think these are better with a proper alias.

Lastly, you may be aware that the `mysql` library is deprecated. If possible, convert your application to use PDO/MySQL or MySQLi.

Comment: Ok I will use it. haha. about the mysql, right, they said that it's deprecated but I'm still learning from basics so I must learn this first before turning to PDO and MYSQLI. thanks a lot. I'll try it. :)

Comment: Heh, I just spotted that it's been mentioned on your previous questions. Alright, I'll stop mentioning it `;-)`.

Comment: I tried removing $contents.=$row['office'].","; and replaced it with print_r($row) and it printed with exact results but not in a table way. It printed as Array => etc etc.

Comment: Indeed it will. This was intended just as a temporary debugging approach, to see what column name has been used by MySQL if you don't add an explicit alias. I've tweaked my answer to make that clear.

Comment: ahh. hahaha. I thought that will print every row. haha. ok, I'll try aliasing. then if no luck, I will use phpmyadmin routines. I like to try it the hard way first before doing the easy way. ;-)

Comment: still got nothing. I think it's because the way that I print the data to excel is by calling their names like empno, id_biometrics. the "timeout" is not a variable but a column made from my subquery. maybe that's why. and because "timeout" is used in getting the hours in timediff, thus its also not showing. Is there any way to print this in excel without my way? :(